# While inserting multiple images to database more than one row are added in main table which is connected to images table

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I'm trying to upload multiple image in codeigniter. For a particular product I want to add the uploaded images to another table calles"image".... while using "lastid" so that I get pid(product id from table product_multi) in images multiples rows are inserted in the product_multi table... the number rows is according to the number of images I upload. 
Someone help me to fix this.. If I'm not using lastid variable passing it works perfectly/... but I want pid in images tables :(

This is how im getting datable[image: This is how getting]

This is my model

```
<?php


class ProductmModel extends CI_Model
{

  var $PRODUCTNAME='';
  var $DESCRIPTION='';
  var $CATEGORY='';
  var $SUBCAT='';
  var $IMAGE='';




public function addproductm()
{
$this->load->database();
$data = array(
"p_name" => $this->PRODUCTNAME,
"p_des" => $this->DESCRIPTION,
"cat" => $this->CATEGORY,
"subcat" => $this->SUBCAT

);
$this->db->insert('product_multi', $data);
$lastid=$this->db->insert_id();
echo "$lastid";
return $lastid;

}


public function addimage()
{
$last=$this->addproductm();
$this->load->database();

$data = array(
"pid" =>$last,
"images" => $this->IMAGE
);
$this->db->insert('image', $data);
}


}
```

controller code::

```
public function upload()
   {



//image upload  
     $config['upload_path'] = './images';
     $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
     $this->load->library('upload',$config);
     $this->upload->initialize($config);

     $fileInfos = array();
     $errors = array();

     //uploading

     if (! empty($_FILES['images']['name'])) 
     {
        $photosCount = count($_FILES['images']['name']);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $photosCount; $i ++)
         {
           $_FILES['image']['name'] = $_FILES['images']['name'][$i];
           $_FILES['image']['type'] = $_FILES['images']['type'][$i];
           $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i];
           $_FILES['image']['error'] = $_FILES['images']['error'][$i];
           $_FILES['image']['size'] = $_FILES['images']['size'][$i];
           if ($this->upload->do_upload('image')) 
           {
                    array_push($fileInfos, array(
                        'fileInfo' => $this->upload->data()

                    ));
                  $filename =$_FILES['image']['name'] ;
                    //$filename =$_FILES["name"].$_FILES["type"];

                      //   $data['fileInfos'] = $fileInfo;
                  $this->load->model("ProductmModel");
                        $this->ProductmModel->IMAGE = $filename;


            }
            else 
                {
                    array_push($errors, array(
                        'error' => $this->upload->display_errors()
                    ));
                }


           }


         }


      $pname = $this->input->post("name");
      $pdes = $this->input->post("pdes");
      $caty = $this->input->post("category");
      $subcat = $this->input->post("subcat");

        $this->ProductmModel->PRODUCTNAME = $pname;
        $this->ProductmModel->DESCRIPTION = $pdes;
        $this->ProductmModel->CATEGORY = $caty;
        $this->ProductmModel->SUBCAT = $subcat;
       $this->ProductmModel->addproductm();


     }
```

This is the code after editing as u said...making both insertion in single function
[image]

[image]

exampleee:

[image]

Comment: use both insert functionality in one function

Comment: Do you have one column for 1 image?

Comment: yessss ..... ihave done similar before..without codeigniter..it worked well

Comment: column for image...

Comment: each images will be uploaded as in more rows in image table

Comment: Let me try to solve the problem.

Comment: okkk...thank youuu so muchh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187842/discussion-between-danish-ali-and-hhhhhh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function upload(){

//image upload  
     $config['upload_path'] = './images';
     $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
     $this->load->library('upload',$config);
     $this->upload->initialize($config);

     $fileInfos = array();
     $errors = array();

     //uploading

     if (! empty($_FILES['images']['name'])) 
     {
        $photosCount = count($_FILES['images']['name']);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $photosCount; $i ++)
        {
           $_FILES['images']['name'] = $_FILES['images']['name'][$i];
           $_FILES['images']['type'] = $_FILES['images']['type'][$i];
           $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i];
           $_FILES['images']['error'] = $_FILES['images']['error'][$i];
           $_FILES['images']['size'] = $_FILES['images']['size'][$i];
           if ($this->upload->do_upload('images')) 
           {
                $data = $this->upload->data();
                array_push($fileInfos, $data['file_name']);
            }
            else{
                array_push($errors, array(
                    'error' => $this->upload->display_errors()
                ));
            }
        }

    }
        $product_array = array(
            "p_name" => $this->input->post("name"),
            "p_des" =>  $this->input->post("pdes"),
            "cat" => $this->input->post("category"),
            "subcat" => $this->input->post("subcat")
        );

       $this->ProductmModel->addproductm($product_array, $fileInfos);

     }
```

**Model**

```
     public function addproductm($product_array, $fileInfos){
        $this->load->database();

        $this->db->insert('product_multi', $product_array);
        $lastid = $this->db->insert_id();

        foreach($fileInfos as $file){
            $image_data = array(
                "pid" => $lastid,
                "images" => $file
            );
        $this->db->insert('image', $image_data);
        }

    }
```

Comment: its still the same..still additional rows are added.. if im using last id thig its happening.. dont know why..thanks for ur time :)

Comment: if i remov lastid query and .. randomly add just a number in pid instead of pid.. it works perfectly...

Comment: @HHHHHH you are assigning last inserted ID to a variable `$lastid` but for insert in `image` table using variable `$last`

Comment: even if correct it it still getting same.... additional rows are added according to the number of  images

Comment: what is the result of this? print_r($image_data);

Comment: Array ( [pid] => 73 [images] => IMG_20170629_184759.jpg ) 74Array ( [pid] => 74 [images] => IMG_20170629_184829.jpg )

Comment: The images are added to database..... the only problem is with main upload.... i want these 2 images cme under pid 73.... but its added as pid 73..and next for 74.. cz an additional row added there like duplicate..... but im not using last id ...and just add "0" or "1" in array.... it works fine :(

Comment: its okay if u cant helpp..thanks for trying and your time :)

Comment: Nothing is imposible bro. Add controller code in your question. I think function is calling twice.

Comment: addedddd the controller function